# kickstart unattended install of OEL 6.5 always asks to check media

Tags: installation, rhel6, kickstart, anaconda

My configuration is as follows:
Hyper-V 2012 R2 Host
Oracle Enterprise Linux 6.5 VM Guest being installed from an iso attached to the VM.

I created a kickstart file that I have on a NFS share and when I boot the virtual DVD I press tab and append ks=nfs:XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:/OEL6.5/test3.ks

It loads the file fine and starts the install but it always asks if I want to test the media.

I do not have "mediacheck" in my kickstart file and according to RHEL if this option is not in the ks file then it should not prompt the checking of the media.

https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7-Beta/html/Installation_Guide/s1-kickstart2-options.html

Below is my kickstart file

```
#platform=x86, AMD64, or Intel EM64T
#version=DEVEL
# Firewall configuration
firewall --enabled --service=ssh
# Install OS instead of upgrade
install
# Use CDROM installation media
cdrom
# Root password
rootpw --plaintext password
# System authorization information
auth  --useshadow  --passalgo=sha512
# Use graphical install
graphical
firstboot --disable
# System keyboard
keyboard us
# System language
lang en_US
# SELinux configuration
selinux --disabled
# Installation logging level
logging --level=info
# Reboot after installation
reboot
# System timezone
timezone  America/Phoenix
# Network information
network  --bootproto=dhcp --device=eth0 --onboot=on
# System bootloader configuration
bootloader --append="crashkernel=auto rhgb quiet" --location=mbr --driveorder="sda"
# Partition clearing information
clearpart --all  
# Disk partitioning information
part swap --fstype="swap" --size=8192
part /boot --fstype="ext4" --size=500
part / --fstype="ext4" --grow --size=1

%post --nochroot
######## Get repo and install Oracle preinstall then update ########
cd /etc/yum.repos.d/
wget http://public-yum.oracle.com/public-yum-ol6.repo
yum install oracle-rdbms-server-11gR2-preinstall
yum update



%packages
@base
@basic-desktop
@cifs-file-server
@client-mgmt-tools
@compat-libraries
@console-internet
@core
@debugging
@directory-client
@ftp-server
@general-desktop
@graphical-admin-tools
@hardware-monitoring
@internet-browser
@java-platform
@large-systems
@network-file-system-client
@network-tools
@nfs-file-server
@performance
@perl-runtime
@security-tools
@server-platform
@server-policy
@system-admin-tools
@x11
aide
arptables_jf
arpwatch
audispd-plugins
audit-viewer
certmonger
device-mapper-persistent-data
dos2unix
dropwatch
ebtables
firstaidkit-gui
genisoimage
krb5-workstation
logwatch
lslk
mtools
oddjob
pam_krb5
pax
perl-DBD-SQLite
policycoreutils-gui
python-dmidecode
sabayon
sabayon-apply
samba-winbind
setroubleshoot
sg3_utils
sgpio
squashfs-tools
system-config-kickstart
system-config-lvm
tigervnc-server
tuned-utils
unix2dos
wireshark
wireshark-gnome
wodim
x86info

%end
```